# MS Graph PS commands to elevate/join users to privileged security group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[image: -]
A user who is eligible to enter this group should be able to activate his memebership just like any other priviaged role.

I am writing a script that can be used to elevate a user to a privileged role or a privileged security group

I can use `Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleInstance` to activate an eligible role assignment for a user.

Is there a similar command that activates Privileged Identity Management for Groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one eligible assignment under **`Groups`** for a user in PIM like this:

[image]

To **retrieve** these details via PowerShell, you can run below MS Graph PowerShell command:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "PrivilegedEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"
Invoke-MgFilterIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupEligibilityScheduleInstanceByCurrentUser -On "principal" | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **activate** this eligible assignment via PowerShell, I ran below script and got response like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "PrivilegedAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance

$params = @{
    accessId = "member"
    principalId = "userId"
    groupId = "groupId"
    action = "selfActivate"
    scheduleInfo = @{
        startDateTime = Get-Date
        expiration = @{
            type = "afterDuration"
            duration = "PT2H"
        }
    }
    justification = "Activate assignment."
}

New-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, role **activated** successfully to group as below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create eligibilityScheduleRequest - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedaccessgroup-post-eligibilityschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)

Comment: I added more context to my initial question. Hope this is more clear now.

Comment: You can check the updated answer!

Comment: Thanks!. This works. However, I also needed to add this scope too Connect-MgGraph -Scope "PrivilegedAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup" for it to work.

Comment: I am also trying to deactivate this assignment once it is no longer needed. I am using the below command. Is this right but I am unable to find what to pass in for the parameter?

Remove-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -PrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequestId

Comment: Could you post a separate question with more details like images from Portal and your code so that I can try it from my end?

Comment: The new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77667682/deactivate-user-assignment-to-a-group-with-pim