# Deactivate user assignment to a group with PIM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I activated PIM for an eligible group using the command

```
New-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -BodyParameter
```

Now, After completing my task I want to exit the role by deactivating this assignment. From the documentation, I figured I could use the below command. But this is not working and is giving me a bad request error.

[image]

```
Stop-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -PrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequestId
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred as you are using **wrong** command to deactivate the user assignment from PIM group.

I have one **active** assignment to group in PIM under `Groups` tab as below:

[image]

When I ran your command to **deactivate** the above assignment, I too got **same error** as below:

```
Stop-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -PrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequestId xxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **deactivate** the active assignment of user from PIM group, you need to use below PowerShell commands with action as **`selfDeactivate`** like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "PrivilegedAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"

$params = @{
    accessId = "member"
    principalId = "userId"
    groupId = "groupId"
    action = "selfDeactivate"
}

New-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupAssignmentScheduleRequest -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, active user assignment **deactivated** successfully from PIM group as below:

[image]

**Reference:** [Create assignmentScheduleRequest - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedaccessgroup-post-assignmentschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#request-body)